# Copy all project. Docker file command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Just started to work with docker and I can't figure out how copy all project files into docker image?

Let's say we have structure:

----my-app

-------------------api

-------------------config

-------------------lib

-------------------public

-------------------Dockerfile

-------------------index.html

So, how can I copy all these folders and files into docker container? What command in Dockerfile should I use?

Super easy solution is to use multiple time **COPY** command. But I believe, that it's wrong way

Comment: put your files in a repository, and do a `git clone` or `hg clone` of course you will need to install git or mercurial before, and remove them after, see as an example https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/simh_alpine/

Comment: @user2915097, nice! Thank you.  Using of git might be possible solution.

Comment: `COPY . .` or `COPY ./ ./` might be actual solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your files in a repository, and do a `git clone` or `hg clone` of course you will need to install git or mercurial before, and remove them after, see as an example

hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/simh_alpine

Answer (score 1):

As I seen in Dockerfile documentation on `COPY` says:

> The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from  and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path .

Therefore you can copy a whole directory.

Comment: OK, I know about it. But how I copy whole project using this command?

COPY ../my-app /usr/src/app

Doesn't work as expecting

Comment: @TK-95 it did not work because you tried to copy a directory outside the build context. To it to work you can only copy files inside the same folder of your `Dockerfile`, so you can't copy `../my-app`, but it will work with `./my-app`

Comment: using `copy` instead of `git clone` will make your container smaller once you don't need the `git` component

Comment: @TK-95 Why just do not symlink the directory to Dockerfile position and try to copy the symlink?

Answer (score 0):

`docker cp` command will do the work for you

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

Comment: this is used after the creation of an image and launching a container using this image.